# Php missing url-encoding

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$markupimage = substr($product_info['image'],0,strrpos($product_info['image'],".")) . "-" . $popw . "x" . $poph . substr($product_info['image'],strrpos($product_info['image'],"."));
```

this currently outputs with `$markupimage =`:

http://shop.example.com/image/cache/data/**NEW WEBSITE**/Products/Hangers/Tees/Full Body/front_black-1000x1000.jpg

Where the 'NEW WEBSITE' text is, the php has missed out the url encoding. It should be `NEW20%WEBSITE`. How can I alter the php script to include this url encoding?

EDIT:
This is where I use this php script:

```
$this->document->setFBOG('og:image', HTTP_SERVER . 'image/cache/' . $markupimage);
```

I have tried wrapping this in both the `rawurlencode()` and `urlencode()`

So far I have tried:

```
$this->document->setFBOG('og:image', urlencode(HTTP_SERVER . 'image/cache/' . $markupimage));
$this->document->setFBOG('og:image', rawurlencode(HTTP_SERVER . 'image/cache/' . $markupimage));
```

This results in a link that looks something like:

```
http://shop.example.com/image/cache/data%2FNEW+WEBSITE%2FProducts%2FHangers%2FTees%2FFull+Body%2Ffront_black-1000x1000.jpg
```

Comment: I don't see that you used `urlencode()`. Try it. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: I didn't actually code this script, I am just trying to modify it so that it works correctly for twitter cards. Where would I add/replace the urlencode() php code?

Answer (score -1):

You can use urlencode() function for that.

```
  urlencode()
```

Comment: I have tried the following but results in server error: `http://shop.example.com/image/cache/data%2FNEW+WEBSITE%2FProducts%2FHangers%2FTees%2FFull+Body%2Ffront_black-1000x1000.jpg`

Comment: I tried this: `$markupimage = urlencode(substr($product_info['image'],0,strrpos($product_info['image'],"."))) . "-" . $popw . "x" . $poph . urlencode(substr($product_info['image'],strrpos($product_info['image'],".")));`